# Find missing numbers in file

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a data file with a bunch of out of order numbers, one per line. I want to see which numbers, if any, I am missing.

example data:

```
1
2
2
3
4
2
6
7
8
3
```

Best attempt:

```sh
cat myfile | sort -n -u | awk 'NR!=$0'
# output:
6
7
8
```

This kinda works. It prints out all the numbers where the line number doesn't match the contents of that line, which tells me at least that I missed 5, but only by printing all of the numbers afterward.

Is there a good way of doing this in awk/sed/bash/sort/etc, or do I have to pull out the python?

I also wanted to find the duplicates in the file and their counts, but `cat file | sort -n | uniq -c -d` appears to have worked perfectly for that.

Comment: Use each value as the key in an awk array. Also put the highest value in a variable. At the end, loop from 1 to highest, and check if each value is in the array.

Comment: @anubhava, for this instance, yes. I think my answer would work for any starting number, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `awk`:

```
awk '{a[$0]++; if ($0 > max) max=$0} 
    END { for (i=1; i < max; i++) if(!(i in a)) print i }' < myfile
```

`a` is an associative array that uses each number in the file as the keys. `max` contains the highest number in the file.

At the end we just check every number from 1 to `max` to see if it's in the array.

Comment: That looks like a good way as well! Can you check if my way also works? I'd love feedback about my attempt if you've got the time.

Comment: Alright, I think I understand what your code does (it took me a minute to realize you're incrementing the value of that's stored under the key of `$0`). That's nice that it can also give info on duplicates. Thanks for showing me!

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I think I figured it out (though feel free to tell me if I screwed up)

```sh
cat file | sort -n -u | \
awk 'BEGIN{range=0};{
     if(++range!=$1){
      for (i=range; i<$1; i++)
        {print i}
      range=$1
      }
    }'
```

It increments a counter that starts as the line number, checks if the value of the line is equal to that. If it's equal, increment and move on.

If it's not, go through all the numbers between expected and actual, and increment the expected accordingly

It seems to work!

Comment: Your method is essentially the same as your original code, since `range` is the same as `NR`

Comment: My original code would have printed out every number after a single miss, and I don't think this does, by virtue of incrementing a second time if we get into the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

With `bash` and `sort`, `seq`, `uniq` utilities from `GNU coreutils`, and assuming that each line in the file `numbers.txt`  is a positive integer, this two-line program prints out numbers in the "gaps".

```
nums=$(sort -nu numbers.txt)
{ seq ${nums##*$'\n'}; echo "$nums"; } | sort -n | uniq -u
```